# Exceptions not caught in release build (WinForm desktop app, C#, VS 2010)

Tags: c#-4.0, release, try-catch, unhandled-exception

I developed a desktop application, it's almost done but still contains some bugs which I'm eliminating.

I use a general [try...catch] block wrapped around my application

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   try
   {
       program = new Program();
       // ...
   }
   catch (Exception x)
   { 
       // ...
       MessageBox.Show(
          message,
          Resources.MESSAGEBOX_ERROR_CRASH_Caption,
          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   } 
}
```

my Program class constructor being:

```
public Program()
{
    // [...]
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // [...]
    frmLogon = new Logon();            
    Application.Run(frmLogon);
}
```

to ensure that any unhandled exception will bubble all the way up the stack and is at least responded to with some communicative message box.

It works fine when I run the application under Visual Studio (debug mode), but when I deployed it and installed on my PC, it doesn't - that's what I get when the bug (which I've already identified, by the way) causes it to read from a null array

[image]

Why? It baffles me really. Why was it "unhandled"? It was my understanding that **try...catch** should work regardless of whether it's release or debug mode, otherwise what would be the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of old, but if you still need a solution, you need to handle some events, enclosing the entire thing in a try catch won't work. Do something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ProcessAppException;
        Application.ThreadException += ProcessThrException;
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    private static void ProcessAppException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        XtraFunctions.LogException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
        throw (Exception)e.ExceptionObject; //MessageBox in your case.
    }

    private static void ProcessThrException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        XtraFunctions.LogException(e.Exception);
        throw e.Exception; //MessageBox in your case.
    }
```

When an exception isn't caught, it will go through one of those before displaying the exception dialog. So you have the option to override it and display a nice message of your choice.